# How to connect and transfer data between iOS and Android devices within the range using Google Nearby Connections API?

Tags: ios, google-nearby-connections

I'm trying to create an app, which discovers devices around it and can transfer data to a selected device from the list of device detected.

The problem I'm facing is that I am not able to get the Google Nearby Connection API for iOS. Is there any Google Nearby Connection API for iOS?

Is there any way, where I can connect one iOS device to one Android device (and vice versa) and transfer data between those two devices using Google Nearby Connection API?

Comment: Please refer this link, hope it helps and work for you.
https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-started

Answer (score 2):

You can't communicate iOS and android via nearby connections. Neaby messages can.

[image]

[Source](https://developers.google.com/nearby).

Your choices are offline with android or online with iOS and Android.